# Replace dictionary's empty values python

Tags: python, dictionary

First of all, I'm modifying another guy's code.

I'm trying to print the values of dictionary that correspond to a `key` like so:

`print (map(str, dict[key]))`

All works fine, but there are some fields that are printed with just the double quotes, like so `['some_value', '', 'other_value', etc...]`, what I'm trying to accomplish here, is to replace the single quotes `''`, with `n/a`

my approach, at first, was to do this: `print (map(str.replace("\'\'", "n/a"), dict[key]))`, but I get the `TypeError` message: `TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`

How can I work around this?

Comment: Can you post your dictionary? As well as full code?

Comment: if possible, please post your sample code

Comment: the values are read from a pickled file, which the other guy unpickled first. Ι know it's not much of a help, but this is all I've got... It's pretty poorly written code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map function needs func and iterable

```
data = { '':'',1:'a'}
print (map( lambda x: x if x else 'n/a', data.values()))
['n/a', 'a']
```

for value as list:

```
data = { 'a' :[1,'',2]}
print (map( lambda x: str(x) if x else 'n/a', data['a']))
['1', 'n/a', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
print([k if k else "n/a" for k in map(str, dict[key])])
```

Comment: are  you sure it work? are you saying [k for k in ['','1'] if k else "n/a"] will work?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just expand to a for loop and write:

```
for value in dict.values():
    if value == "":
        print("n/a")
    else:
        print(str(value))
```

Comment: You could convert this to a list comprehension if you want to `[print("n/a") if value == "" else print(str(value)) for value in dict.values()]`

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem in a more simple way without using map(). Just use list() than you can loop on every single character of your string (diz[key]) and then replace the empty space with the 'n/a' string as you wish.

```
diz[key] = 'a val'
[w.replace(' ', 'n/a') for w in list(diz[key])]
>> ['a', 'n/a', 'v', 'a', 'l']
```